# get characters from string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a textfile that consists of multiple blocks such as one shown here :

```
TestVar 00000000  WWWWWW 222.222 222.222 222.222
UNKNOWN ,,,,,,,,  ,,,,,,  ,,,,,,
```

I would like to get the folowing output:
Each part is always 8 characters long (e.g TestVar  , 00000000)
From each line that start with testvar i would like the code to return:

```
WWWWWW_00000000
```

Can someone help me with this I have used regex before but never with python and am quite new to both of them.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need regexp? Could you just split each line and take the 2nd and 3rd elements?

Comment: @PierreGM - Regex is easy to use here, as OP needs also check if string begins with **TestVar**, so it can be done in one step...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex pattern `^TestVar\s+(\d{8})\s+(\S+)` you can get that as >>

```
import re
p = re.compile('^TestVar\s+(\d{8})\s+(\S+)')
m = p.match('TestVar 00000000  WWWWWW 222.222 222.222 222.222')
if m:
    print 'Match found: ', m.group(2) + '_' + m.group(1)
else:
    print 'No match'
```

Test this demo [here](http://ideone.com/OAs5J).

---

To find all occurrences in multiline `input` string use:

```
p = re.compile("^TestVar\s+(\d{8})\s+(\S+)", re.MULTILINE) 
m = p.findall(input)
```

---

To learn more about regex with Python, see http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Comment: At first thank you very much. Could anyone by change explain then how to put this regex in python code to check it on a string?

Answer (score 2):

assuming you dont want us to write the code for you
here is a link that is quite specific
http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#regex-howto

keep in mind you will likely want to use the findall()...
and also write your code using r' instead of constantly needing the backslashes...

you might want to show us the code you wrote already and isnt working so we can help you better
gl

Answer (score 1):

You mention multiple occurrences of the pattern, in which case you could use [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) along with [`re.MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE):

```
input_string = """
TestVar 00000000  WWWWWW 222.222 222.222 222.222
UNKNOWN ,,,,,,,,  ,,,,,,  ,,,,,,
TestVar 22222222  AAAAAA 222.222 222.222 222.222
UNKNOWN ,,,,,,,,  ,,,,,,  ,,,,,,
"""


import re
pat = re.compile("^TestVar\s+(\d{8})\s+(\S+)", re.MULTILINE)
matches = pat.findall(input_string)

# Result: matches == [('00000000', 'WWWWWW'), ('22222222', 'AAAAAA')]

for num, let in matches:
    print "%s_%s" % (num, let)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regexp:

```
lines = ["TestVar 00000000  WWWWWW 222.222 222.222 222.222",
         "UNKNOWN ,,,,,,,,  ,,,,,,  ,,,,,,"]
print [toks[2].strip(' ')+'_'+toks[1] for toks in \
        [[line[i:i+8] for i in xrange(0,len(line),8)] for line in lines] \
       if toks[0] == 'TestVar ']
```